# How to increment a column based on two tables that are joined

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am trying to increment a column on a sql server table based on the join between the initial table and the joined table.  The idea is to update `tblForm10Objectives`, set the `ObjectiveNumber` column to an increment number starting with 1 based on the number of rows returned from the join of `tblForm10GoalsObjectives` and `tblForm10Objectives` where `ID_Form10Goal` equals a number.  Example query so far:

```
Update tblForm10Objectives 
Set ObjectiveNumber = rn
From (
    Select ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION by OG.ID_Form10Goal) as rn
        , *
    From (
        Select *
        From tblForm10GoalsObjectives OG
    Join tblForm10Objectives O On OG.ID_Form10Objective = O.ID_Form10Objective
    Where OG.ID_Form10Goal = 4
    Order by O.ID_Form10Objective
) as tblForm10Objectives;
```

If the select portion of the query is performed the columns are displayed so you can see the `ObjectiveNumber` is currently 0 where `ID_Form10Goal` = 4

Once the update runs I need for the `ObjectiveNumber` to show 1 , 2; since there are two rows for `ID_Form10Goal` = 4.

**I had to introduce a new table to the logic of this update statement, the table name is tblForm10Goals.  The objectives need to be pulled by ID_Agency instead of ID_Form10Goal  I am getting an error message stating a "a multipart identifier 'dbo.tblForm10Objectives.ID_Form10Objective = rns.ID_Form10Objective' could not be bound.  I am using the following SQL Update statement:**

```
UPDATE dbo.tblForm10Objectives
SET ObjectiveNumber = rn
FROM tblForm10Goals As g
    Left Join tblForm10GoalsObjectives gobs ON g.ID_Form10Goal = gobs.ID_Form10Goal
    Right Join 
(
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY g.ID_Agency
                            ORDER BY OB.ID_Form10Objective) AS rn,
        OB.ID_Form10Objective

    FROM tblForm10Goals g
    LEFT JOIN dbo.tblForm10GoalsObjectives gobs ON g.ID_Form10Goal = gobs.ID_Form10Goal
    RIGHT JOIN dbo.tblForm10Objectives OB ON gobs.ID_Form10Objective = OB.ID_Form10Objective
    Where g.ID_Agency = 2
) rns ON dbo.tblForm10Objectives.ID_Form10Object = rns.ID_Form10Objective
```

Comment: Do you mean that `ObjectiveNumber`, in one row, needs to contain the string value `'1, 2'`, or that there should be two rows, each with an incrementing value, `1` and `2` respectively?

Answer (score 1):

Your example seems to be missing a closing parenthesis somewhere, and without the table structures to look at, I can't be certain of my answer.  It seems you have two tables:

```
tblForm10Objectives
-------------------
ID_Form10Objective
ObjectiveNumber
...
```

and

```
tblForm10GoalsObjectives
------------------------
ID_Form10Goal
ID_Form10Objective
...
```

If this is the case, the following query should give you the results you desire:

```
UPDATE dbo.tblForm10Objectives
SET ObjectiveNumber = rn
FROM dbo.tblForm10Objectives INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY OG.ID_Form10Goal
                            ORDER BY O.ID_Form10Objective) AS rn,
        O.ID_Form10Objective
    FROM dbo.tblForm10Objectives O INNER JOIN
        dbo.tblForm10GoalsObjectives OG ON OG.ID_Form10Objective = O.ID_Form10Objective
    Where OG.ID_Form10Goal = 4
) rns ON dbo.tblForm10Objectives.ID_Form10Objective = rns.ID_Form10Objective
```

If you run the inner SELECT statement, you will see the desired `ObjectiveNumber` values and the corresponding `ID_Form10Objective` that will get updated with those values.

If you post your table structures, I or someone else may be able to be of more help.